# Higher density medium tube from sea level to space for travel

Tags: launch, low-earth-orbit, design-alternative

Is it theoretically possible to build a strong sealed tube from Earth's sea level all the way to Space, fill it with a medium (such as water) that has a higher density than humans. And then humans enter their tube at sea level and medium automatically pushes the human all the way up. Please see attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: If youve got the tower, it makes more sense to fill the inside with an elevator.  This scheme is not free work. The energy required to insert something into the bottom will be more than the energy buoyancy will provide on lifting… either you push the sub in through some magic membrane and must apply a massive force to beat the water pressure, or you use an air-lock type system, but then you have to pump the water introduced into the air-lock back into the cylinder.  Either case, you dont save any energy.  An elevator would be much more energy efficient! And much less complex. +1 cuz its neato.

Answer (score 5):

As it's been said, [space is fast, not high](https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/) (or, staying in space that is). Your "with/without gravity" diagram is therefore, not accurate. It's even a stretch to label those "with/without atmosphere", since it's more of a gradual continuum of lessening density, but the Kármán line is generally accepted at about 100 km for being the boundary of "space". That doesn't mean there's no gravity there - the majority of the earth's gravitational pull is still felt. After all, the Moon is also captured by the Earth's gravitational pull.

Given magic materials, sure you could build a tube like that, but it wouldn't actually help much with your people actually *staying* in orbit.

The top of your tube wouldn't be going faster than 0.5 km/second, when orbit a similar height is more like **8** km/second. If you look at [sounding rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_rocket), they go up to "space" and fall right back to the ground, since most of their energy is spent going upwards. Any orbital rocket is going to spend a **lot** of energy going *sideways* instead, once it gets out of the thicker part of the atmosphere

This wouldn't be too dissimilar from [Space Diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_diving) that was brought into the news a decade ago by Felix Baumgartner, who jumped from about 39 km up, which isn't *quite* as high as you're suggesting, but you'll note that he fell right back to the ground.

---

Bottom line:

- The dividing line for "with gravity" vs "without gravity" is not an accurate model when thinking about space
- Something similar could be useful, which is known as a [Space Elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator) but currently we don't have the materials to make one work (among other issues). A sealed tube structure filled with water of the size you propose would seem ... *unfeasible*

Answer (score 4):

[Fyrepenguin went through](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/63637/26356) the physics of the tower part, but the water part is also interesting. A column of water 100km high is 10 times deeper than earths [deepest ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariana_Trench#Descents), which it is possible to build very special submarines to visit, but not something you can just climb into wearing swim wear. In fact at that depth many things do not actually float, [instead getting crushed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trieste_(bathyscaphe)).

The doors at the bottom to get in would be a most interesting construction, the basic thickness of at least a meter. This is because for a 100 km tower with a vertical tube of one square meter area there is 100 000 cubic meters of water, which weighs one hundred thousand tonnes which will want to get out that door.

Also relevant here is that in vacuum [water will do some combination of freezing and boiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram) so the top end of the tube will tend to evaporate until it freezes over.

If you can build a vertical tube like this, it probably makes more sense rather than fill it with water instead pump it down to vacuum, allowing you to use it as a launch tube for a [space gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_gun) which otherwise suffer greatly from atmospheric drag.

Comment: Given the ability to build such a structure, I'm willing to believe in personal submersibles to use to ascend, though you're spot-on that a normal human will be crushed. You do bring up an interesting point regarding the fun part of the water phase diagram at the top of the tower.

Comment: Even if the human wasn't crushed (eg, using tricks like [liquid breathing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_breathing)) they'd _still_ die, because that much pressure will interfere with cellular biochemistry cos the various bits will compress to slightly different degrees and stop interacting correctly.